# Dynamic Input Field in Tabbed Form

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin module from https://marmelab.com And used their "Edit" component. So the "Edit" component is calling a backend api that will fetch the data of record. my JSON data is:

```
{
  id: '1',
  szName: 'Very First',
  iCNBPrice: '60',
  iBEPrice: '215',
  iEmailPrice: '555',
  iMaxConvert: '0',
  iConvertFee: '0',
  iServiceCharge: '0',
  iInvoiceEOM: [ 1 ],
  iInvoiceDate: [ 1 ],
  iInvoicePropertySold: [ 0 ],
  iInvoiceRecurring: [ 0 ],
  iDiscountAfterMagazine: '0',
  iMagazineDiscountPeriod: '0',
  iActive: '2',
  iDeleted: '0',
  dtDeleted: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  iDeletedBy: '0',
  iCreatedBy: '1',
  dtCreated: '2019-08-07 00:00:00',
  iUpdatedBy: '99',
  dtUpdated: '2019-08-21 17:35:34',
  price_product: [
    { szType: 'Tilstandsrapport', iPrice: '100' },
    { szType: 'Elinstallationsrapport', iPrice: '20' },
    { szType: 'Energimærket', iPrice: '30' },
    { szType: 'Kladde', iPrice: '40' },
    { szType: 'Inspiire', iPrice: '50' }
  ],
  Nemforsikring: '5',
  FRIDA: '5',
  'Willis/DBF': '5'
}
```

And i want to make `price_product` fields with using "SimpleFormIterator" component but not able to get correct source name and label for fields ?

```
<ArrayInput source="price_product" label="" className="price_feild">
                    <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd >
                    <NumberInput  source={source.szType} validate={required()} style={{ display: 'inline', float: 'left', marginLeft: '20px' }}/>
                    </SimpleFormIterator>
                </ArrayInput>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to parse, so I might be misinterpreting what you are trying to achieve, but: Have you tried using just `source="szType"` in the `NumberInput`?

Comment: In NumberInput i want price_product[iPrice] in my source and price_product[szType] in my label. In source the price is coming (yes for this i will change source="iPrice"). But I can't get label dynamically price_product[szType]   

Does label accepts functionor How i can achieve this ? Please help and thank for your answer in advance.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you're trying to accomplish, I think. That is probably not going to work with just the predefined input components in react-admin, you are going to need some custom elements. Something like a custom `FormIterator` that gets the label from the `szType` field, and supplies that to the `NumberInput` for each array entry, perhaps.

Comment: Just realized `FormDataConsumer` might also help you; see the examples in the Input component docs' [Linking Two Inputs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs) section.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to add a dynamic label to the NumberInput but an alternative solution would be to add an additional (disabled) input and display the type that way.

```
<ArrayInput source="price_product" label="" className="price_feild" >
  <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd >
    <DisabledInput
      label='Product Type'
      source='szType'
    />
    <NumberInput
      label='Product Price'
      source='iPrice'
      validate={required()}
      style={{ display: 'inline', float: 'left', marginLeft: '20px' }}
    />
  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this will not work for me as this will create two seperate field and my requirement was different.I need a dynamic label for each price_product array not a seprate field.